# Contains test for python objects

Tags: python

How does Python `__contains__` work for lists if I use arbitrary objects for elements?
Will it revert to the `is` operator? Or does it use `__eq__` if provided?

A simple test gave

```
class Test: pass

print(Test() in [Test()]) # -> no
a=Test() 
print(a in [a])   # -> yes
print(a in [Test()])  # -> no
```

So can I assume it uses the comparison by references `is`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `__contains__` implementation for list just compares the object with the `==` (`__eq__`) operator.
It is this operator that, if not defined for a class, defaults to the behavior of  `is`.

In short, "a in lst" is the equivalent to:

```
def contains(obj, lst):
   for item in lst:
       if obj == lst: 
          return True
   return False

contains(a, lst)
```

The behavior of `==` does change whether `item` implements `__eq__` explicitly, and defaults to object identity (`is`) otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation of `object.__contains__(self, item)`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__contains__#object.__contains__):

> Called to implement membership test operators. Should return true if item is in self, false otherwise. For mapping objects, this should consider the keys of the mapping rather than the values or the key-item pairs.
>
> For objects that don’t define `__contains__()`, the membership test first tries iteration via `__iter__()`, then the old sequence iteration protocol via `__getitem__()`, see this section in the language reference.